How to replace a clip in the timeline with another near identical clip, maintaining in-out points?
How to replace a clip in the timeline with another near identical clip, maintaining in-out points?
Let's say I have a 2 minute clip, call it One. The timeline shows the clip at 5:00, with in and out points set to 0:30 and 0:40 respectively.
I want to replace clip One with clip Two, that is also 2 minutes. I want to keep the same in-out points as One. How to do this?
FCPX appears to provide the following options:

"Replace": replaces the clip with the new clip. Sets the in-out points on the new clip to show the entire clip, all 2 minutes of it
"Replace from start": maintains the length of the clip in the timeline. Sets "In" to 0:00. Sets "out" so that the clip takes the same time as before, in this case will be "0:10"
"Replace from end": as for 'replace from start', but now the "out" will be set to 2:00, and the "in" will be set to 1:50
"replace with retime to fit". makes the new clip play at very high speed, so that it fits in the same time on the timeline (from 5:00 to 5:10), even though out is now set to 0:00, and out is set to 2:00
thee seems no option to replace the clip, preserving the in-out positions?

